# Have a profile field item from user registration show on a users page

Tags: users

I have created a new checkbox field through the core module 'profiles' called Billing Terms. It is visible on the user registration form.

I'd simply like an asterisk `*` next to the users name on their profile page if the Billing Terms checkbox is ticked. Actually it doesn't have to be an `*` but rather anyway to signify that the Billing Terms checkbox was ticked.

Any help or helpful links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is if you have a custom template in your theme for user profiles. [Creating a custom user profile template](http://drupal.org/node/35728)

Basically, you can overwrite the entire layout of the user profile this way. And then, you can output profile fields however you like by simply printing them. For instance:

```
<?php print $account->CHECKBOX_FIELD_NAME; ?>
```

This will allow anyone visiting the profile to view the results.

If you wish to display this to only users of a specific role, you would want to wrap the above code in an *if* and check what the viewing users role it.  For example, something like this

// Check to see if $user has the administrator role.
   if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    CHECKBOX_FIELD_NAME; ?>
   }
  ?>

Comment: Is there a way I can, as admin, view another users profile and see whether the checkbox was ticked? I believe the above solution would work for a logged in user viewing their own profile, correct?